# run csh scripts from bash, change shell temporary via command

Tags: linux, bash, tcsh

I need to run csh scripts from a bash shell and therefore temporary change to tcsh via a command. It works perfect in interactive mode but i cant figure out in a one line command.
So in interactive mode i do in the bash shell:

tcsh

source my.tcshr

useMyTcshCmd

etc.

How can i do all of this in 1 command?
Sorry for the newbie question...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
tcsh -c "echo foo; echo bar"
```

Result:

```
foo
bar
```

So this should work:

```
tcsh -c "source my.tcshr; useMyTcshCmd"
```

Comment: looks great, i give it a try tomorrow at work. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the interpreter directly in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
echo "doing stuff"
```

And then simply run the script:

```
./script
```

Comment: kind of doesnt work as it is several csh scripts interacting. And the .tcshr setup is needed first. Already spent a while trying

Comment: You should do that inside the script. And I don't see any problem with it, I do this all the time (although I use bash, but the principle is the same).

Comment: @user501743: In other words, use a wrapper script that sources your dot file and runs each of the other scripts.

Comment: tcsh -c "setenv TEST bla;echo $TEST"
TEST: Undefined variable.
how would i do a wrapper file? 
tcsh -c "setenv TEST bla" echo $TEST
TEST: Undefined variable.

hm....

Answer (score 0):

```
tcsh -c useMyTcshCmd
```

Comment: i need to source my.tcshr first, so it will be a chain of commands really. tcshr needs to set global environmet variables.

Comment: tcsh reads .tcshrc when it runs.  Not sure why you would want to name it my.tcshr. Perhaps you could include this file inside .tcshrc

Comment: it is not in the home dir so tcsh wont find it

Comment: hm, so the problem is that the stuff i set in .tcshr is unavailable for further commands when i do 

tcsh -c "source /opt/fuelpipe/use/use-0.1.0/share/.tcshr; echo $myvar"
myvar: Undefined variable.

Comment: even this fails:
tcsh -c "setenv TEST bla;echo $TEST"
TEST: Undefined variable.

tcsh -c "setenv TEST bla" echo $TEST
TEST: Undefined variable.

Comment: got it (use is an alias set in .tcshrc)
tcsh -c "eval source /share/.tcshrc; eval use -list"